# Help to understand difference between に堪える/に堪えない/に耐える/にたえない

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

この活動が社会に認められることは、誠に喜び。。。。
A.にたえません 
B.にたりません  
C.に当たりません  
D.にかたくありません  
 The answer is A にたえません  
First there are two words: に堪えない and に耐えません  , with different 漢字 of course different meaning 
に堪えない: can't suppress emotions(?)抑えない  
 
But also means ~だけの価値がある？
に耐えない: can't stand to do

According to the sentence above, it is suppose to express emotion of happiness  
人の悪口は聞くに堪えない  
この説はまだ証拠が少なく、詳細な議論に堪えるものではない (This opinion still has little evidence and does not fit/worth a detailed discussion)

So what I want to ask is what is the real meaning of に堪える/にたえない
It expresses worth/not worth doing something, but also has meaning to express strong emotion like 喜びに堪えません(？) 
喜びに堪えません: not worth to feel happy/really happy?
Thank you!!!

Comment: I think it's just "endure" or "make effort to keep the state", 喜びに堪えない = can't hold back joy, 聞くに堪えない = can't stand to listen etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

〜に堪えない is rather idiomatic.

> **終止形(辞書形, dictionary form)** + **に堪えない**

In this case 堪えない means "*not worth doing*", and by extension "*cannot do it because it is unpleasant.*"

> **enotional noun(e.g. 喜び, 悲しみ)** + **に堪えない**

Here 堪えない means "*cannot help feeling*" or "*cannot suppress emotions*"

By the way, 感に堪えない and 感に堪える is the same meaning "*be impressed deeply*." Such a phenomenon sometimes occurs in Japanese. e.g 満遍なく-満遍に(the latter is obsolete), おぼろけなり-おぼろけならず(old Japanese), 何気なく-何気に(the latter is slangy)

Comment: Thankyou so much for the clarification!!!! At first i was confused but i think i got it!!! If it is emotional noun then it means cannot suppress and if jisho form it means not worth doing! Thankyou :D